# Safe integer counter that wraps as soon as MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is reached?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a counter in my program that increments a number each invocation.

Even though `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is a very large number, I don't like the idea of having a "timebomb" in my program.

Is this a real concern, or is the number sufficiently large that I shouldn't bother with implementing a function that wraps around when `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is reached?

```
function incrementWithWrapAround(n) {
  if(n === 9007199254740991) { // Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
    return 0;
  }

  return ++n;
}
```

Comment: If you tick 1 million times every second it will take 285+ years to reach that value.

Comment: @zerkms, But what if initial value is `9007199254740991 - 1` ?

Comment: Then your question must have some some clarification about the initial state. Btw, your current code does not increment anything. PS: or even `n + 1`, since it expresses your intention more clearly.

Comment: @Me.Name it will not increment after that. It's not a comparison, it's a precision problem. There is not enough bits to represent distinguishable numbers, so the counter will basically stick to the same value.